# PHP Error/exception handling related to missing extensions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Many a times there is this or that PHP extension required to make our PHP application work.

The difficult part is we cannot check for each and every extension that our project requires specially when we are using a framework. We are assuming some of these extensions are popular they should be enabled by default.

Sometime user installs our application on fresh/dedicated server with not so well configured PHP and even some basic extension we assume should be active are not.

Is there some class where errors related to extensions can be caught. So basically whenever an error occurs related to some extension we can direct the user to a special page and ask them to enable this extensions, so they don't think that error is related to application but with missing extension missing.

How do we do better exception handling for such errors/exceptions?

Comment: I don't see any solution around this because you are developing something, not the application is developing it. Laravel have a very decent Exception Handler with 2 functions though if this is not enough I can't think of anything else: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#the-exception-handler

Comment: How about an install/bootstrap script which explicitly checks the existence of required extensions and spells out any problems to the user?

Comment: Our application is open source and people install it on their own server and lately we came across some error reports where some basic php extensions were also not enabled, this is something we never accounted for and if we build an exception class to catch such error we need to know these errors in advance. Some was wondering if someone has already build such a class to catch exceptions related to php extensions not enabled, specially all the php extensions that Laravel needs.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a PHP question than a Laravel question. [Laravel requires](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2#server-requirements) mcrypt, mbstring, openssl.. etc by default as do most other/any decent PHP web application/framework. In some cases as well, your project may require additional modules.

In PHP however, you can use the [`extension_loaded`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php) function to find out if an extension is loaded. e.g.

```
if(!extension_loaded('mcrypt')){
    //maybe try to load it or display a nice 404 error page
}
```

You could put the above code block in your index.php for example and display your own custom 404/500 page to tell the user there's a problem nicely.